# exampe of using AsyncParametersClient for multiple params

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a parameter node to store all the params that define a robot using the guide [HERE](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-global-parameters/#ROS2_YAML_parameters).

The examples show are for only one param, how would you do set it up for multiple params? Do I really have to do all those lines of code for each param?

```
class TestGetGlobalParam : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    TestGetGlobalParam() : Node("test_get_global_param")
    {
        parameters_client = 
            std::make_shared<rclcpp::AsyncParametersClient>(this, "/global_parameter_server");
  
            parameters_client->wait_for_service();
            auto parameters_future = parameters_client->get_parameters(
                {"my_global_param"},
                std::bind(&TestGetGlobalParam::callbackGlobalParam, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        }
        void callbackGlobalParam(std::shared_future<std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter>> future)
        {
            auto result = future.get();
            auto param = result.at(0);
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Got global param: %s", param.as_string().c_str());
        }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::AsyncParametersClient> parameters_client;
};
```

While I know ROS2 is trying to get away from global params, but for the project I have envisioned it's the best way I can think of. I am trying to write a set of packages for legged robots (3 or 4 dof, and 4, 6 or 8 legs) where the user defines their robot via YAML and the code sets up the low level controller for IK, gait, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364650/exampe-of-using-asyncparametersclient-for-multiple-params/) by [lutinplunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/62191/lutinplunder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2020-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The call to `get_parameters` may take one or more parameter names. Check out [this demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/15be86210cfb6a528bd012bf1347388bc9f3200b/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/set_and_get_parameters_async.cpp#L75) where multiple parameters are requested in a single service call:

```
parameters_client->get_parameters({"foo", "baz", "foobarbaz", "toto"});
```

Also note, the type of the future argument in the callback is a vector of parameters. This vector should contain all of the parameters requested.

Hopefully this answers your question.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lutinplunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/62191/lutinplunder/) on 2020-11-04**:
thanks jacobperron, the ROS2 documentation is even worse than the ROS1 version. given what you told me and what the demo shows I should be able to make it work by using get_parameters to retrieve all the variables I need and then simply map the necessary values from the array to a local name.